# Is there a generalization of transfinite recursion that allows defining proper classes?

Tags: set-theory, recursion, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

Transfinite recursion lets one define a sequence of sets $S_\alpha$, for $\alpha$ an ordinal. My question is whether it is possible to generalize this recursion to allow $S_\alpha$ to be classes, not just sets. I would be thankful for a reference to such a generalization.

In the Wikipedia article, the transfinite recursion is formalized using a class function $G: V \rightarrow V$, where $V$ is the class of all sets. The $S_\alpha$, for $\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}$, is in particular a value of $G$, so it belongs to $V$ and thus is a set. This suggests that the generalization I'm looking for would run into a problem, because now values of $G$ would have to be classes, so we couldn't use a class function anymore. But maybe there is some other approach that goes around this problem.

Comment: $\Sigma^1_n$-transfinite recursion scheme over second-order set theories could be relevant. You can find its details on [Williams' doctoral dissertation.](http://kamerynjw.net/research/pubs/diss/kwilliams-diss-ss.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me work with second-order set theories like $\mathsf{NBG}$ to handle classes more conveniently.

It depends on the complexity of classes you want to define. For example, the trivial sequence of classes (e.g., $S_\alpha=V$ for all $\alpha$) does not require any machinery beyond $\mathsf{NBG}$. However, not every class enjoys such property.

Before explaining the 'difficulty' of class recursion, let me start with a positive result: Morse-Kelley set theory $\mathsf{MK}$ proves such recursion is possible. More specifically, $\mathsf{MK}$ proves

> **Theorem.** ($\Sigma^1_\omega$-transfinite recursion) Let $\phi(x,Y,P)$ be a formula of second-order set theory, with a class parameter $P$, and $R$ be a well-founded class relation with the transitive closure $<_R$. Then there is a class $S\subseteq \operatorname{dom}R\times V$ such that
> $$(S)_r=\{x:\phi(x,S\upharpoonright r, A)\}$$
> for all $r\in \operatorname{dom}R$, where $S\upharpoonright r:=S\cap \{r'\in \operatorname{dom}R\mid r'<_R r\}\times V$.

(In fact, $\Sigma^1_\omega$-transfinite recursion is equivalent to the full second-order separation scheme over $\mathsf{NBG}$.)

We can see that $\Sigma^1_\omega$-transfinite recursion works with a class well-order instead of ordinals. The reason is that class well-orders may have a longer 'length' than the class $\mathrm{Ord}$ of all ordinals: $\mathrm{Ord}+1$ or $\mathrm{Ord}\cdot 2$ would be easy examples.

As we may expect, transfinite recursion over 'longer' well-order and 'with a more complex $\phi$' requires much power. According to a diagram in [Williams' doctoral dissertation](http://kamerynjw.net/research/pubs/diss/kwilliams-diss-ss.pdf) (printed page number 58, pdf page number 66 of the linked paper), the complexity of $\phi$ affects more the strength of the transfinite recursion scheme than the length of $<_R$. (Also note that Willams used $\mathsf{GBC}$ and $\mathsf{KM}$ for denoting $\mathsf{NGB}$ and $\mathsf{MK}$ respectively.)

We can see that transfinite recursion for first-order formulas (what Williams called $\Sigma^1_0$-formulas) of length $\omega$ proves the truth predicate of a first-order set theory exists. However, $\mathsf{NBG}$ does not prove there is a truth predicate of a first-order set theory since $\mathsf{NBG}$ is a conservative extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Thus, $\mathsf{NBG}$ has some non-definable classes. The truth predicate of first-order set theory is an example as we saw. Another example of a non-definable class over $\mathsf{NBG}$ is the class forcing relation, which is proved in

> Victoria Gitman, Joel David Hamkins, Peter Holy, Philipp Schlicht, and Kameryn Williams. "The exact strength of the class forcing theorem." *The Journal of Symbolic Logic* 85.3 (2020) pp. 869 - 905.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. So I see that unfortunately there is no such generalization in NBG. The result in MK is interesting though.